# Simulate tcp window full on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tcp

I have 2 ubuntu boxes. In between them is a firewall.
I am trying to simulate tcp window full condition or in other words, I want the ubuntu server to send a tcp window full flag to client. Here are the tcp values on the ubuntu client.

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem:8970 11963   17940
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_rmem:4096        87380   3092256
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem:4096        16384   3092256
```

I also disabled window scaling on the client.

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling:0
```

Test: I then using scp transfer a 2GB file from server to this client. 
On the firewall, i can capture the packets. I dont seem to hit the tcp window full condition.
Bigger question is that the window size value is hitting a max of 65535. Is there any way to reduce that window size value on ubuntu so I can force the tcp window full condition sooner ?

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu you can change the value of `net.core.wmem_max = 16777216` in */etc/sysctl.conf*

Comment: On my client (192.168.2.1), i put the values of /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default, /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default, /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max and /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max to be 10. Then when I do a scp from client to server, still the SYN packet from client to server says win=14600. Why is that ?

Comment: Looks like in kernel 3.0 and above window size is 10 * MSS. MSS = 1460 (MTU of 1500 - 40)..  So window size by default is 14600. to reduce MSS, use ip route command to set a mss of your choice.